# Android Plugin DDMS not showing up on Eclipse Perspective

Tags: android

Although the DDMS plugin is installed (verified by checking the installed plugins) in Eclipse, it is not showing up in the Perspective (which is showing only JAVA & DEBUG). Any help with this would be great. Thanks, animesh

Answer (score 8):

You can find **all** perspectives by opening the menu *Window > Open Perspective > Other...*. The two perspectives shown at the top right are just shortcuts to commonly used ones. If you open the DDMS perspective from the aforementioned menu it will now show at the top right.